# Generating .txt(PIPE Seperated) file on Unix application server using oracle database with 2 million rows

Tags: oracle, unix

I have a requirement, where there are about 2 million rows of data and 1000 columns in 1 table in oracle database. I want this data to be dumped out from this table into a .txt file with PIPE as separator. This file should be created on UNIX application server and not on database server. After that, the file will be FTPed to other server, where it will be loaded by other application. This process of generating file should be fast(in like 1 hour max)

Any suggestions, as to what will be the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you use sql*plus? It has the feature of spool. Please read about it.

Comment: The last time I used Oracle on UNIX (15 years ago?), I used `sqsh` to talk to it. It was not easy to compile and configure correctly, but hopefully that has gotten better, or maybe there are better Oracle tools for UNIX now. We can’t (shouldn’t) write a script for you. Please get your basic connection to the DB working and ask specific questions about a part of the script you are stuck on, but you have to try writing something yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming: The application server has Oracle software installed, including SQL*Plus, and can access the database server.

To expand on @Popeye's comment, create a file `dump_stuff.sql` and put in it something like:

```
set pagesize 0
set linesize 50000
set trimspool on
set trimout on
set feedback off
set markup csv on delimiter | quote off
set feedback off

col owner format a30
col object_name format a50
col subobject_name format a50
col object_type format a30

spool stuff_output.txt

select owner, object_name, subobject_name, object_type from dba_objects;
spool off
```

Invoke SQL*Plus on the application server, connect to the target database, and do the following:

```
set termout off
@dump_stuff
```

On my database, dumping 78,000 rows from dba_objects took just over 2 seconds.  The termoout off command prevents output going to the screen, but still goes to the spool file.

Sample output:

```
OWNER|OBJECT_NAME|SUBOBJECT_NAME|OBJECT_TYPE
SYS|UNDO$||TABLE
SYS|C_COBJ#||CLUSTER
SYS|PROXY_ROLE_DATA$||TABLE
SYS|I_CDEF2||INDEX
SYS|I_PROXY_ROLE_DATA$_1||INDEX
SYS|FILE$||TABLE
SYS|UET$||TABLE
SYS|I_FILE#_BLOCK#||INDEX
...
```

You will need to modify the value for the `set linesize 50000` to be long enough to avoid your data from the 1,000 columns from wrapping around.

Documentation of the SQL*Plus `set` command: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-A6A5ADFF-4119-4BA4-A13E-BC8D29166FAE